# Деплой Angular приложения на Firebase

Tags: webpack, firebase, angular, развертывание

Делаю по шагам

1. `ng build --prod` OR `ng build --prod --aot` (пробовал и так, и так)
2. `firebase init`
3. `firebase deploy`

Менял шаги местами (первый со вторым) все равно выдаёт одно и тоже. Белый экран после деплоя, и ошибки следующего вида. Как будто не видит файлы в папке.
Структура билда следующая:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

HTML:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибки в браузере:

[image: Не видит стат. файлы]

Подскажите как исправить белый экран, чтобы приложение заработало?

UPD: Не знаю, что случилось, но оно запустилось.

Comment: Т.е. у вас заработало в итоге и вы ничего не изменяли? Могу я вопрос закрыть как невоспроизводящийся?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Именно. Ничего не менял, оставил как есть, но через некоторое время обновил страницу и заработало.